# Dynamically rendering component from string: ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to call a component dynamically like this

```
var Tagname = 'Species';
options.push(<Tagname {...attrs}/>);
```

And im getting a warning in the console as

```
Warning: <Species /> is using uppercase HTML. Always use lowercase HTML tags in React.
Warning: The tag <Species> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
```

All other codes are working fine. But this component does not working.
How can i fix this?

Comment: `React.createElement(Tagname, attrs)`

Comment: @TryingToImprove I also tried with this and same console warning arrives

Comment: See the warning. The first one says that you are using uppercased HTML inside your render. Do you do `<DIV....` for instance?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes you can call the component dynamically, but it should be the component itself not the string.

Like this:

```
var Tagname = Species;    //component itself, not string
<Tagname {...attrs}/>;
```

Because JSX will get compiles into `React.createElement(Component, props, ...children)` and `Component` will be a string if it a html tag, otherwise a react component.

So if you pass `React.createElement("Species", props, ...children)`, react will treat it as a html tag not a react component.

**Update:**

You can do one thing, create a map for each component, Like this:

```
const Map = {
  "componenet1": Component1,
  "componenet2": Component2
}
```

Now you can access the component using the string key, like this:

```
let name = "componenet1";
let Tagname = Map[name];
<Tagname {...attrs}/>;
```

Comment: Thanks Mayank. This works. But i have the value Species in a variable and when i tried to assign the variable it takes only as string.   Eg: var Tagname=this.state.value; How to fix this?

Comment: @HareeshSNair, you can do one thing, create a map of string and component name, and use that map to get the component from string, check the Update section of the answer :)

Comment: Would it be correct to render anything from my app? let's say I do import * as MyComponents from 'components', where I get all of them and then I can choose from there using my string as an index.

Comment: @rmartrenado yes that will also be a good option, save the mapping in a different file then render them using some string.

Answer (score -1):

The following works for me...Just pass as full component tags from parent component and render in child component's jsx as normal variable.

**Parent component:**

```
export const ParentComponent = () => {
    const rows = [
      {component: <Comp1 />},
      {component: <Comp2 />},
    ]
    return ( <ChildComponent rows={rows} /> );
   }
```

**Child component:**

```
export const ChildComponent = ({rows}) => {
     return(
      <div>
          {rows.map((r)=>{
            return(
              r.component
            )
          })}
      </div>
     )
   }
```