# Dynamic component name - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three components:

```
const Comp0 = () => <div>1</div>;
const Comp1 = () => <div>2</div>;
const Comp2 = () => <div>3</div>;
```

I have also a class, with state:

`state = { activeComponent: 0 }`

This `activeComponent` can be changed by user to `1`, `2` or `0`.

In render, I have:

```
return (
   {React.createElement(`Comp${this.state.activeComponent}`)};
}
```

It should work... theoretically. However - Im getting a really weird error. Two errors.

1. `Warning: <Comp0 /> is using uppercase HTML. Always use lowercase HTML tags in React.`
2. `Warning: The tag <Comp0> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.`

How is that possible that they appear simultaneously?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `React.createElement(...)` creates a `DOM` element and not a React component

Comment: @devk, no it creates a React component too, https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html

Comment: Why do you do it like this? Why don't you just use an if statement?

Comment: @JanickFischer What if I have 100 components? Using if for every case would be an overkill.

Comment: If you have 100 components, you may as well put them into a state array, as I show below. How else would you keep track of them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically rendering component from string: ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863490/dynamically-rendering-component-from-string-reactjs/48864866#48864866)

Comment: @Patrickkx got the reason why its not working?, hope that will solve your issue.

Answer (score 11):

You could simply render the dynamic tag like

```
const Tag = `Comp${this.state.activeComponent}`;
return (
   <Tag />
}
```

According to the **[docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime)**:

> You cannot use a general expression as the React element type. If you
>   do want to use a general expression to indicate the type of the
>   element, just assign it to a `capitalized` variable first.

In your case it doesn't work because, you are passing the string name to React.createElement whereas for a React Component you need to pass the component like

```
React.createElement(Comp0);
```

and for a normal DOM element you would pass a string like

```
React.createElement('div');
```

and since you write

```
`Comp${this.state.activeComponent}`
```

what you get is

```
React.createElement('Comp0')
```

which isn't quite understandable to react and it throws a warning

> Warning: `<Comp0 />` is using uppercase HTML. Always use lowercase HTML
>   tags in React.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to create a custom component element with `React.createElement`, you have to pass the direct class/function, instead of its name (that's only for DOM elements), to it, e.g. `React.createElement(Shoot0)` instead of `React.createElement('Shoot0')`;

You can circumvent the issue by putting the components you intend for in array and index them

```js
const Shoot0 = () => <div>1</div>;
const Shoot1 = () => <div>2</div>;
const Shoot2 = () => <div>3</div>;

const Shoots = [Shoot0, Shoot1, Shoot2];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeComponent: 0
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {
          activeComponent: (prevState.activeComponent + 1) % 3
        }
      })
    }, 1000)
  }
  
  render() {
    return React.createElement(Shoots[this.state.activeComponent])
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do a function with a mapping like this:

```
const stateArray = [Comp0, Comp1, Comp2];
const getComp = (Comp) => <Comp>
const getCompFromArray = (i) => getComp(stateArray[i]);
```

Comment: I dont feel rly well with that solution... I would rather avoid putting every imported component inside an array.

Comment: For what reason? You aren't globally calling components, are you? What's the usecase? Also, have you looked at @Shubham 's solution?

Comment: Ye, I import them from global scope