# React Iterate over object and dynamically render in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a dynamic response as below

```
let resp = {
"Comp1" : {name: "Component 1", component: {}},
"Comp2" : {name: "Component 2", component: {}}
}
```

In my JSX, I want to iterate and dynamically render the components (something like below). I am having issues writing the syntax and also handling the case where "resp" would be undefined initially.

```
Object.entries(resp).map(([key,value],i) => <resp[key].component key={i}>)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Check for undefined: `resp ? Object.entries(resp).map(([key,value],i) => <resp[key].component key={i}>) : null`

Comment: Thanks...Actually the above syntax is not working at all...so I am doing something entirely incorrect.

Comment: You're iterating over the entries, `resp[key] === value`. But what would you expect from `<{} key={i}>`? It's not even a complete JSX element, there's no closing.

Comment: If `value.component` is actually the component object, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/48863490/3001761